# Miui camera crashes right after talking any picture

Tags: android, camera

I have installed pixel experience from in my Redmi note 10 pro, after some time when I went back on stock ROM and tried to use the camera it got crashed just after talking photo, it happens every time, I have already tried clean installation of stock ROM again and also tried other version please someone help me.

Logcat:

````
msg: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: getCameraCharacteristics:747: Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device -1: No such file or directory (-2)
stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getCameraCharacteristics:747: Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device -1: No such file or directory (-2)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1270)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:592)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:669)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:965)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:986)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:824)
    at com.xiaomi.camera.imagecodec.impl.VirtualCameraReprocessor.openVTCamera(VirtualCameraReprocessor.java:2)
    at com.xiaomi.camera.imagecodec.impl.VirtualCameraReprocessor.createCaptureSessionIfNeed(VirtualCameraReprocessor.java:17)
    at com.xiaomi.camera.imagecodec.impl.VirtualCameraReprocessor.checkConditionIsReady(VirtualCameraReprocessor.java:8)
    at com.xiaomi.camera.imagecodec.impl.VirtualCameraReprocessor.access$1500(VirtualCameraReprocessor.java:1)
    at com.xiaomi.camera.imagecodec.impl.VirtualCameraReprocessor$ReprocessHandler.handleMessage(VirtualCameraReprocessor.java:13)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: getCameraCharacteristics:747: Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device -1: No such file or directory (-2) (code 3)
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2440)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
    at android.hardware.ICameraService$Stub$Proxy.getCameraCharacteristics(ICameraService.java:812)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:571)
    ... 13 more
New Snippet  Fork 
 Memochō ```

How to solve this error ??
````

Answer (score 1):

do a fastboot flash of stock rom with all the wipes.
It is better to flash the oldest possible stock firmware

Comment: Okay, will give it a try